# Spark Stage error when performing PCA analysis in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, pca

when I run the below line of code

```
>model_pca <- tbl(sc, "flights") %>% select(air_time,distance,dep_time) %>% 
ml_pca()
```

results into a stage failure but I cannot understand the reason

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$3: (struct<air_time:double,distance:double,dep_time_double_vector_assembler_801c364a4ab0:double>) => vector)
```

It says user defined function but I am not using any user defined function, have I missed any package installation or is it because I am using spark 2.2.0 with hadoop 2.7

Below is the full error message:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in 
stage 12.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined 
function($anonfun$3:
 (struct<air_time:double,distance:double,dep_time_double_vector_assembler_801c364a4ab0:double>) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null.
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$assemble$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$3.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:98)
    ... 27 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2119)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1026)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1008)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1128)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistics(RowMatrix.scala:419)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeCovariance(RowMatrix.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computePrincipalComponentsAndExplainedVariance(RowMatrix.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Transformed$class.foreach(IterableViewLike.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
        at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.co
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the "%>%" operator in your code. What it does depends on the library you're importing or how you defined. Try to "unchain" that.

Comment: Thanks, will try today and respond.

Comment: Unchaining did not help, I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Can you post the code of your second try and update the answer?

Comment: Apologies for late reply, was able to workaround it. I think it was the sequence in which libraries were added.